# Can a nice enough ODE always be extended to the complex plane?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose I have a first-order ODE $y' = f(x, y)$, where $y: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, and $f \in \mathbb{R}[x, y]$. Consider $f^\mathbb{C} = i(f)$, where $i: \mathbb{R}[x, y] \to \mathbb{C}[x, y]$ is the usual embedding, and the equation $w' = f^\mathbb{C}(x, y)$, where $w: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ is meromorphic.

> Let $y$ be an analytic solution of $y' = f(x, y)$. Is its complex continuation $w$ necessarily a solution of $w' = f^\mathbb{C}(x, y)$?

Sorry if it's a silly question, my complex analysis is very rusty :( My motivation is that I want to solve a Riccati equation $y' = y^2 + C^2$. If I could count $y(x) = iC$ as a solution, I would be able to solve the equation exactly.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $f$ is meromorphic. Everything is (locally) analytic, so expanding the differential equation as a power series gives you the result you want, right? Away from poles in $f$ the equality of power series for the real case implies it for the complex case.

If $f^\mathbb C$ is not complex differentiable on the real line (the standard $\exp(-1/x^2)$ for instance explodes at the origin) then at these points the method fails.

This isn't necessarily very useful, though. I don't see why the complex version of Riccati equation having a constant solution is particularly interesting *for the real equation*. It only seems to tell you about complex solutions, no? Haven't checked this, but I'd be surprised if this generated real solutions.

Comment: It's interesting because I can reduce it to a Bernoulli equation, no?

Comment: Not every well-behaved function $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is analytic, a counter-example is $f(x)=e^{-\frac{1}{x^2}}$ (or rather the continous extension thereof, i.e. set $f(0):=0$) IIRC. All the derivatives (or, again, rather their continous extension) vanish at $0$, yet the function obviously isn't identical to $0$ on *any* neighbourhood of $0$. This has pratical implications e.g. for numerical methods - those often fail to converge for such right-hand-sides, since their proofs of convergence depend on the RHS being analytic.

Comment: I misread the part about $w$ being merom. - I thought it referred to $f$. Sorry.

Comment: What about the bump function? The points at which we join the exponential and the constant parts of this function (w.l.o.g $-1$ and $1$) have the trivial Taylor expansions, yet in no interval does it converge to them.

Comment: That's the same example fgp gave; I just misread the question as I said. I was looking at the nice (polynomial!) case you were motivated by. I've edited my answer (:

Comment: But isn't it a counterexample to your claim that everything is locally analytic?

Comment: It's not a claim, it's an assumption about $f$. You get nothing if you don't make this assumption, that's the point of the counterexample.