# Can I extend these ODE formulas to complex numbers?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, complex-numbers

In my calculus class, we recently covered first-order, linear ODEs. Specifically, we discussed the formula for the solution of one (and its derivation):
$$y=\frac{1}{u(x)}\int Q(x)u(x)dx$$
where $u(x)$ is the integrating factor defined by
$$u(x) = e^{\int P(x)dx}$$
all of which can be used to solve an ODE of the form
$$\frac{dy}{dx}+P(x)y=Q(x)$$
I was impressed by the beauty of this solution, and I wondered if this could be extended to other situations - specifically, a first-order linear ODE defined on $\mathbb{C}$. Is this possible?

Note: I found this post ([Can a nice enough ODE always be extended to the complex plane?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/384248/can-a-nice-enough-ode-always-be-extended-to-the-complex-plane)) which was certainly interesting, but the answer seemed a little hard to understand (I'm a high-schooler taking a second AP Calculus class); also, I'm primarily interested in the formulas I named above, and in this specific linear first-order case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is yes.

Nevertheless, restrictions do apply: All the functions should by holomorphic and the domain simply connected (to make the integral have a unique meaning).

Say, $\Omega\subset\mathbb C$ simply connected, $P,Q\in\mathcal H(\Omega)$ and $z_0\in\Omega$. Then the IVP
$$
w'=P(z)w+Q(z), \quad w(z_0)=\omega,
$$
has a unique solution, namely
$$
w(z)=\omega\exp\left(\int_{[z_0,z]}P(\zeta)\,d\zeta\right)+\int_{[z_0,z]}\exp\left(\int_{[z_0,\zeta]}P(\eta)\,d\eta\right)Q(\zeta)\,d\zeta.
$$

Comment: Thanks. I'm curious about the long answer, though.

Comment: Thats under a topic of mathematics called complex analysis. Its way above ur current level though. You will only learn it when u hit ur second or third year of your university studies and thats if u are a maths major.

Comment: @HDE226868: See EDIT. - But ys wong's comment is quite appropriate.

Comment: Thank you both. Something to look forward to, I guess.